# how to call javascript function in main document from within iframe (ckeditor plugin)

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor

I've built a simple CKeditor 3 plugin with one button that should just call a JS-function when somebody clicks it.

The plugin (code when somebody clicks) looks like this and is working:

```
var openAssetsBrowser = {
    exec:function(editor){
        openAssetsBrowser();
    }
};
```

I always get the error "openAssetsBrowser is not a function"

The function itself is somewhere in the page, I thought the order shouldn't matter since the whole page is read first, before anyone would lclick the ckeditor button that triggers the function

Calling it on a link somewhere (e.g. with jquery) in the page just works:

```
$("a#linkOpenFileManager").click(function(){
    openAssetsBrowser();        
        return(false);      
});
```

Does anyone know why the function cannot be called from within the CKeditor plugin?

update: when pasting the complete function code instead of "openAssetsBrowser();" in the plugin, all works, but that's not really re-usable code...

Comment: it must have something to do with CKeditor running in an iFrame ?

Comment: the solution will be: finding a way to get to the original document where the ckeditor iframe is residing and calling the function there. Don't know how to get the document though...

Answer (score 1):

now that was easy.

**parent**.openAssetsBrowser() did the trick!